# Question about the validity of Michael Grossman, Robert Katz and Jane Grossman Non-Newtonian / Meta / Multiplicative Calculus

Tags: differential-calculus, metamathematics

I am no mathematician by far, but I have studied diff. and integral calc and beyond, in my undergrad years.  I recently came upon this book:
"The First Systems of Weighted Differential and Integral Calculus"
https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=mS8g4XfaOEUC&printsec=frontcover&pg=GBS.PA45#v=onepage&q=%22Non-Newtonian%20Calculus%22&f=false

which belongs to this subject:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus

Looks like there are only a few players here, almost like a family business.
I have never seen a math book that introduces so many new symbols and refers to itself as meta-calculus.  Which also sounds like it would have a similar scientific significance as Meta-physics.

Can someone validate this to be an authentic and legitimate field of mathematics, or is this some bogus wanna be calculus?

Here is a random snippet (albeit taken out of context), that looks nonsensical in detail and as a whole.  Does this make sense to anyone?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the [talk page of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Multiplicative_calculus) you linked mentions some  possible problems. See also [AfD for Non-Newtonian calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Non-Newtonian_calculus_(2nd_nomination))

Comment: @MartinSleziak. thanks, It does have the smell of junk, but the commentators are mostly critical with the acclamation of the WP post, rather than the mathematical validity of the subject.   I wish I had more advanced knowledge to rip this "calculus" to shreds

Comment: Also, on MathOverflow we avoid critiquing whole works so as to avoid flame wars/possible legal disputes.  (Hopefully someone will recall and link to the related meta discussion.) If there is a mathematical looking snippet whose validity you wish to check, you might ask here or on math.stackexchange.  Try to make it brief and self contained.  Gerhard "Not Ready For New Calculi" Paseman, 2017.09.19.

Comment: The differential calculus component is just exactly the study of the exponential of the logarithmic derivative $f'/f$. The problem with exponentiating that is that it doesn't extend naturally to several variables, where we can work with the very useful $df/f$, but $e^{df/f}$ is meaningless. So I would encourage the use of logarithmic derivatives, but not of multiplicative differential calculus. The product integral is a well known object in calculus, and does not need or justify an appellation of "multiplicative calculus". I would not encourage anyone to study multiplicative calculus.

Comment: Note that in general this site is for research mathematicians, not really meant as a service for the public.  You should expect to get answers at the level of research mathematics, assuming at least graduate-level knowledge.  If that isn't going to be useful to you, then I suggest http://math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge  research mathematicians are exactly who's answer I am seeking..

Comment: @Nate, I think if the public wants to learn what is advanced mathematics and what isn't, MathOverflow is a good place to ask, especially if the public asks in a useful way.  While the bias of the poster toward the subject seems negative, the rest of the question is sincere and useful.  Note the question is not of the form "Is what I'm doing advanced mathematics?".  Gerhard "Research Mathematicians Are Public Too" Paseman, 2017.09.19.

Comment: First of all, WHY are you asking? There is a lot of junk published. Why do you want to spend efforts and investigate whether a particular piece is junk or not?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, because I want to raise public awareness about fraud that impersonates science.  As mentioned, I have not seen any public denouncement of this "work", and now, there is.

Comment: The acclaim attributed to Struik, Grattan-Guiness, Boas, etc. on the WP talk page looks a little weird (at first glance anyway), but putting the possibility of fraud there aside, I don't see a reason to assume that the actual mathematical content is wrong or invalid. It just strikes me as banal, or unimportant, or pointless. But it's such a fringe topic; if you want to raise awareness about fraud posing as science, I'd think you'd have much bigger fish to fry than this. Unless there's some (very unexpected) breakthrough, I think you can just ignore it.

Comment: @ToddTrimble.  I am not on a witch hunt for junk scientists.  I occasionally dabble in "reading" post graduate math books,  This is the first time I came across an instance of junk science in mathematics realm.  So I sought consensus here on on the subject matter of mathematical rigor which this book seems to attempt.  So far I had mostly received questions of my ambitions, instead of assessments of the subject.  And just because there is large fraud out there, doesn't mean that we should neglect smaller fraud, in the realm of intellectual integrity.  This fraud, still unvetted after 50 yrs

Comment: @LastTribunal, so far, the only one I see saying it is a fraud is you, and I am not seeing you back up that claim.  The work of Katz, Grossman and Grossman may not be as revolutionary as they hope, but I am not seeing anything mathematically wrong so far.  If it is the same as the pamphlet I dimly remember, then I recommend you stop calling it fraud (or substantiate your claim of fraud).  It may not take over the educational world as a substitute for calculus, but neither has discrete mathematics.  Gerhard "Learn It If You Want" Paseman, 2017.09.19.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend searching for critiques of this material.  I remember a pamphlet on this back in the 80's;  if it is the same subject, it is likely a published critique exists and is indexed on the Internet.

Based on the snippet, it resembles some mathematics I have seen published under a yellow cover.  I am loath to dismiss it as nonsensical.

Gerhard "Yellow Journalism Comparison Not Intended" Paseman, 2017.09.19.

Comment: Thanks, I have not been able to find any critiques other than that was referenced in the comments

Comment: And it is possible that no notable critique was ever published.  Either no one cared to bother, or no one wanted to step on the toes of a fellow "mathematician"

Comment: If they call it "the best thing since sliced bread" at the start, it is more likely to be viewed as crankish.  While I would not call the subject mainstream or widely known and used, it looks like an honest effort to generalize Newtonian calculus and find applications.  It may be a corollary of results in functional analysis couched in challenging notation and possibly not worth studying, but I'm not the person to make that call.  Gerhard "Not A Calculus Of Variants" Paseman, 2017.09.19.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: that was basically my reaction too.